# Using PHPmailer all mail landed in spam folder

Tags: email, phpmailer, email-spam

I am using smtp auth then also mail going into spam folder.
If the body of mail contains an external file (file_get_containts) then the mail is going in the Spam folder.

but, if the body of mail contains only string then the mail is going in the inbox folder.

Can someone please help me out with this?

here is my code:-

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

if( isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['phone']) && isset($_POST['message']) ){

$name = $_POST['name'];

$email = $_POST['email'];

$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$m = nl2br($_POST['message']);

$mail   = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'mail.example.in';  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'info@example.in';
$mail->Password = 'nsdfdk^^dsfx7wffdsry8e^';                           
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->From = 'info@example.in';
$mail->FromName = 'John Smith';
$mail->addCustomHeader('MIME-Version: 1.0');
$mail->addCustomHeader('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
$mail->addAddress('example@gmail.com', 'Jay Senghani');

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                       

$mail->isHTML(true);     

$mail->Subject = "New Enquiry from  website";


$message = file_get_contents('emails/admin.html');
    $patterns = array();
    $patterns[0] = '/{name}/';
    $patterns[1] = '/{email}/';
    $patterns[2] = '/{number}/';
    $patterns[3] = '/{message}/';
    $replacements = array();
    $replacements[0] = $name;
    $replacements[1] = $email;
    $replacements[2] = $phone;
    $replacements[3] = $m;
$message = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $message);

$mail->Body = $message;


if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
        echo 'Message has been sent /n';
}

}

// For User Automated Email

if( isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['phone'])){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'mail.example.in'; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                              
$mail->Username = 'info@example.in';
$mail->Password = 'ndfgk^dfgg^gfdggfdgdfgdfx7wfy8e^';                          
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                     
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->From = 'info@example.in';
$mail->FromName = 'John Smith';
$mail->addAddress($email, $name);    
$mail->addCustomHeader('MIME-Version: 1.0');
$mail->addCustomHeader('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  

$mail->Subject = "Thank you for your interest Website ";
// $mail->addAttachment('Attachment Path', 'pdf'); 

$message = file_get_contents('emails/user.html');
$message = preg_replace('/{name}/', $name, $message);

$mail->Body = $message;

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Message has been sent /n';
}

}


?>
```

Here is my admin template:-

```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title></title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="emailWrapper">
        <div id="emailHeader">
          <div class="topBar"></div>
          <a class="branding" href="http://example.com/" target="_blank" >
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/JME5efdRs.png">
          </a>  
        </div> 
        <div id="emailContent">
          <h2 class="greetings">
            Dear Admin,
          </h2>
          <div class="content">
            <p class="intro">
              New enquiry from XYZ Website
            </p>
            <p>
              <strong>Name&nbsp;:</strong>&nbsp;{name}
            </p>
            <p>
              <strong>Number&nbsp;:</strong>&nbsp;{number}
            </p>
            <a class="email">
              <strong>Email&nbsp;:</strong>&nbsp;{email}
            </a>
            <p>
              <strong>Message&nbsp;:</strong>&nbsp;{message}
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="regards">
            <h5><strong>Thanks &amp; Regards,</strong></h5>
            <h6>XyZ</h6>
          </div>
        </div>  <!-- END #emailContent  -->
        <div id="emailFooter">
          <div class="bottomBar">
            <p>
              &copy; 2018 Xyz. All rights reserved
            </p>
          </div>

        </div>  

      </div>  

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You don’t need to add those custom headers - it will break your messages. PHPMailer does it for you. The receiver will often add headers telling you why a message was classed as spam, so read them.

Comment: Is it the same behaviour regrardless of the receiving email service (Gmail, Msn etc.)? Are you sending from your own domain or a shared one?

Comment: @Henkealg yes it is doing same in Gmail, Yahoo, and MSN. yes I am sending from my own domain

Comment: @Synchro, so basically i dont want to add custom headers in PHPMailer, right?

Comment: It’s fine to add *custom* headers, but you are adding duplicates of headers that PHPMailer already provides.

Comment: @Synchro, I removed the duplicate headers and try to send mail but still, it landed into the spam folder

Comment: I didn't say that removing duplicate headers would fix your problem, just that adding them was wrong - otherwise I would have posted that as an answer. You've still not shown us what's in the headers of delivered messages - they will often say *why* a message was marked as spam.

Comment: @Synchro I added the admin.html code above. this message I used to deliver to admin.

Comment: That doesn’t help. Please post the headers from a received message, as shown when you select “view source” or “show original”

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> will not work as all content items need absolute paths.

Comment: @Henkealg ,I am adding an image from another website that's why my email landed into spam folder "<img src="https://i.imgur.com/JME5efdRs.png"> "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troubleshooting email deliverability is tricky mostly due to the lack of details about the inner workings of anti-spam features at the main email service providers (Gmail, Msn, mail.com, Yahoo etc.). The main aspect of good email deliverability is usually your domain reputation. If you are just starting out with a new email domain most receiving services tend to be sceptic towards your first xx number of emails.
If your email contains invalid or poor html it will up the spam score. If you add attachments to it will certainly up the score.

I figure your emails without attachments are just below the threshold for ending up in the spam folder. When adding an attachment it gets just above the same threshold.
Most services also apply per-user rules, so the handling of your emails can be treated differently between receivers within the same service.

As a step in troubleshooting if PHPmailer is responsible for the poor delivery, I suggest setting up an email client like Mozilla Thunderbird and sending some emails from there. 
That will help you figure out the source of the deliverability of your emails.

If you want to avoid thinking about deliverability you can spin up an account with SMTP services like Mailgun.